# Alternative to ul Li {display:inline}

Tags: html, html-lists

I have a set of social media sprites aligned in a row, centered in a container with display:inline but I just realized they don't display at all in Firefox.  What's the best alternative?

Comment: The `inline` property is not buggy in Mozilla. What exactly is going wrong?

Comment: It's common to blame the browser vendors when we have css issues. :) Can you post a link to your site so that we can firebug it?

Comment: Please create jsfiddle to illustrate your bug

Comment: Ok, I just started searching and saw an article somebody wrote that said it was buggy.  I'll post some code when I get to my computer in a little bit, thanks.

Comment: have you tried tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inline elements don't have height. I assume that you're using sprites as CSS backgrounds, so you'll need to use inline-block and set explicit height and width.